# Deeplinks don't work every time on Android (React Native)

Tags: android, adb, deep-linking, back-button

We are developing a cross platform App (which for simplicity I call MyApp) that uses deeplinks to collaborate with other Apps (OtherApps). The base code is made in React Native.

When I send a deeplink to MyApp via OtherApp, the deeplink data is passed to MyApp, then processed and sent back to OtherApp, using another deeplink (from MyApp to OtherApp).

The problem is that on Android it works fine the first time, but it stops working on a second try. I understand that the activity of "going back" from MyApp to OtherApp subsequently prevents us from being able to correctly use future deeplinks from OtherApp to MyApp.

This problem is not found on iOS.

A similar problem occurs on MyApp when I click on the hardware back button ... the deeplinks stop working (only once), if instead I use the task manager to change the App, the problem does not exist.

I tried to inspect **adb** logs and the only now thing I noticed until now is this line:

```
W System  : A resource failed to call release.
```

it occurs twice and only when deep links doesn't work.